# Entity Framework updating with custom value not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

I need to update entity manually. This works on inserting data but while updating it's failing. I should query some manual data before saving model.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Article article, int CategoryID)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        article.Category = db.Categories.Find(CategoryID);
        db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Answer (score 0):

When you're updating data, you need to update all the Categories seperately.  Just updating article won't update the child objects.

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application for more info.